# NHibernate mapping multiple relationships between two tables

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an irritating problem. I've got two objects which are related on two different columns. The relationships are the same (both one-Many) and the structure is as follows

**BRAND table**
ID
Name
[Other stuff]

**CATEGORY table**
ID
Name
BrandID (FK to Brand. Navigation Name Brands) 
DynamicBrandID (FK to Brand. Navigation Name DynamicBrands 
[Other stuff]

But no matter what I try, I can't get this to work in NHibernate. The HBM files look like they've generated correctly for both objects but no matter what I try, every time I want to insert into category I get an error.

My first question - Am I trying something that NHibernate cannot cope with? It's a legacy database so if that's the case, then I have bigger problems.

Secondly - What's going wrong? I get an error along the lines of :

{"Invalid index 26 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=26."} - which I can't dig into any more at all so am flying a little blind

thanks for your help

Comment: Could you please complement your question with your mapping file (or mapping class)?

Comment: There's a lot of cruft on the models which isn't related to the question as I can see - I didn't want to confuse things,but if you really want to see them - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17868024/model.zip

Answer (score 0):

While there is a lack of your mapping files, I would bet that the issue is clear: **doubled** mapping. It very often happens when we do have two represenations of one column:

```
public virtual int   BrandID { get; set }
public virtual Brand Brand   { get; set }
```

And the xml mapping looks like:

```
<property    name="BrandID" column="BrandID" /> 
<many-to-one name="Brand"   column="BrandID" class="Brand" />
```

And this is wrong, because when SQL statement is generated, there are two inserts into one column **`"BrandID"`**. But there is a solution, make one of these mappings **readonly**. Usually the `int` (BrandID) is the better choice, because we still profit from ORM:

```
<property    name="BrandID" column="BrandID" insert="false" update="false"/> 
<many-to-one name="Brand"   column="BrandID" class="Brand" />
```

So, check your fluent and make it like this:

```
References(x => x.Brand, "BrandID");
Map(x => x.BrandID, "BrandID")
  .Not.Insert()
  .Not.Update()
  ;
```

Also check [Error is coming while saving data with many to one mapping in nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679621/)

Comment: What's the point of mapping BrandId explicitly above.  Why not just access it via `Brand.Id`.