# NHibernate firebird error - Index was out of range

Tags: c#, .net, database, nhibernate, firebird

What can cause the following error in c# when using NHibernate and Firebird database?

```
2015-08-17 08:27:04,962 [21] [(null)] ERROR Smartsign.Server.Core.Server Unhandled exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbParameterCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) in c:\Users\Jiri\Documents\devel\NETProvider\working\NETProvider\src\FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient\FirebirdClient\FbParameterCollection.cs:line 58
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbParameterCollection.GetParameter(Int32 index) in c:\Users\Jiri\Documents\devel\NETProvider\working\NETProvider\src\FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient\FirebirdClient\FbParameterCollection.cs:line 315
   at System.Data.Common.DbParameterCollection.System.Collections.IList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at NHibernate.Type.Int32Type.Set(IDbCommand rs, Object value, Int32 index)
   at NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, Object value, Int32 index)
   at NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand st, Object value, Int32 index, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Dehydrate(Object id, Object[] fields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Boolean[][] includeColumns, Int32 table, IDbCommand statement, ISessionImplementor session, Int32 index)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id, Object[] fields, Boolean[] notNull, Int32 j, SqlCommandInfo sql, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id, Object[] fields, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Action.EntityInsertAction.Execute()
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable)
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list)
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions()
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource session)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush()
   at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Commit()
```

Comment: Did that "duplicate mark" helped you Robert? Honestly I doubt it did, because I would expect it'll be about a different issue... Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24278610/1679310 could give some hint

Comment: No. Since this is an issue inside a library (nhibernate and firebird) I use (If it was my code I could have simply used an debugger and solved it in no time..). I will check you link, it gives me a hint on what might cause it so I'll know where to start searching.

Comment: The problem was in fact two properties mapped to the same column. Inheritance made it harder to find.

Comment: I expected that.. great you made it. Good luck with NHibernate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for completeness. The exception:

> Index was out of range...

with NHibernate WRITE operation mostly means: there is doubled column mapping.

Usually combination of the `<property>` and `<many-to-one>`. Also check:

[NHibernate mapping index out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24278582/1679310)